# I tried to upload multi images, but it wasn't display preview photos

Tags: flutter

I tried to upload multi images, but it wasn't display preview photos.

Original code is can display only photo, but I modified the code then tried to upload multi images. Still cannot show to me.

Original Code, working well, but just show one image

```
SizedBox(
                  height: 250,
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 487 / 451,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: MemoryImage(_file!),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Then I tried to modified to this one

```
Expanded(
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    itemCount: selectedFiles.length,
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 3),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Image.file(File(selectedFiles[index].path));
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

It wasn't show to me.

I can got the image list

```
Future<void> selectImage() async {
    if (selectedFiles != null) {
      selectedFiles.clear();
    }
    try {
      final List<XFile>? imgs = await _picker.pickMultiImage();
      if (imgs!.isNotEmpty) {
        selectedFiles.addAll(imgs);
      }
      print("image list : " + imgs.length.toString());
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Or I need to modify this code??

```
SimpleDialogOption(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: const Text('Choose from gallery'),
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                Uint8List file = await pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                // final List<XFile>? imgs = await _picker.pickMultiImage();
                // if (imgs!.isNotEmpty) {
                //   selectedFiles.addAll(imgs);
                // }
                setState(() {
                  _file = file;
                });
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `GridView` to display images the Ui has to rebuild

So when you add images to your list

```
 if (imgs!.isNotEmpty) {
        selectedFiles.addAll(imgs);
      }
```

you dont notify the UI to rebuild.
you can call an empty setstate below the `selectedFiles` to force UI to rebuild.

```
if (imgs!.isNotEmpty) {
        selectedFiles.addAll(imgs);
setState((){
 
    })

      }
```

For example when picking a single file

```
File? myfile;
pickFile()async{
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

if (result != null) {
  File file = File(result.files.single.path);
setState((){
myFile=file;
})
} else {
  // User canceled the picker
}}
```

Comment: I can picking single file, but can not picking multi file

Comment: hence the setstate on pick multiple images

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand :(. Don't know how to modify it :((

Comment: And this will got error `result.files.single.path` Error code `The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.`

Comment: I'd updated my context, could you help check it ?

Comment: Y ou didnt implement my solution. CHeck me answer again